# Cannot create stored function

Tags: mysql

When I try to run this code :

```
DELIMITER $$

create function formatJJhhMMssToSuffixes(duree varchar(100))
returns varchar(100)
begin
    DECLARE
        hhmmss VARCHAR(100);
    if duree = '' then
        return '';
  else if cast(substring_index(duree, ':', 1) as int) = 0 then
        set hhmmss = substring_index(duree, ':', -3);
        return concat(substring_index(hhmmss, ':', 1), 'h ', substring(hhmmss, 4, 2), 'm ', substring_index(hhmmss, ':', -1), 's');
    else
        return concat(substring_index(duree, ':', 1), 'jours ', substring(duree, 4, 2), 'h ', substring(duree, 7, 2), 'm ', substring_index(duree, ':', -1), 's');
    end IF;
end $$

DELIMITER ;
```

then I get error :

```
[SQL] 

create function formatJJhhMMssToSuffixes(duree varchar(100))
returns varchar(100)
begin
    DECLARE
        hhmmss VARCHAR(100);
    if duree = '' then
        return '';
  else if cast(substring_index(duree, ':', 1) as int) = 0 then
        set hhmmss = substring_index(duree, ':', -3);
        return concat(substring_index(hhmmss, ':', 1), 'h ', substring(hhmmss, 4, 2), 'm ', substring_index(hhmmss, ':', -1), 's');
    else
        return concat(substring_index(duree, ':', 1), 'jours ', substring(duree, 4, 2), 'h ', substring(duree, 7, 2), 'm ', substring_index(duree, ':', -1), 's');
    end IF;
end $$

DELIMITER ;

[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int) = 0 then
        set hhmmss = substring_index(duree, ':', -3);
        re' at line 5
```

What is wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

`CAST` dosent have option `INT`, try `SIGNED` instead,

look for various `CAST` options here
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp

editted your code, try this

```
create function formatJJhhMMssToSuffixes(duree varchar(100))
returns varchar(100)
begin
    DECLARE
        hhmmss VARCHAR(100);
    if duree = '' then
        return '';
    else if cast(substring_index(duree, ':', 1) as signed) = 0 then
        set hhmmss = substring_index(duree, ':', -3);
        return concat(substring_index(hhmmss, ':', 1), 'h ', substring(hhmmss, 4, 2), 'm ', substring_index(hhmmss, ':', -1), 's');
    else
        return concat(substring_index(duree, ':', 1), 'jours ', substring(duree, 4, 2), 'h ', substring(duree, 7, 2), 'm ', substring_index(duree, ':', -1), 's');
    end IF;
end $$
```

Comment: I noticed that it is the first if statement which causes the error : whgen I removed it then the error is gone ! So what is wrong in the if statement ?

Comment: but as per the error in the post, you have it on line 5, which is having cast

Comment: I already considered your suggestion to modify the cast to be unsigned. But after that , the if statement caused error.